# Obtain HTML class name from Rails dom_id method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So the `<a class="buttonDone">` line, I have an `id="<%= dom_id(item) %>"`. The **show.html.erb** is basically a snippet of the `if-else condition` for a certain item's date is greater than today's date, or is equal to today's date, or is less than today's date.

The problem is, that in my **update.js.erb**, I'm trying to make sure that once it reaches a certain condition, I'm trying to add a certain .css class (i.e. `.complete`) to the `<a class="notDue">` or `overDue` or `dueToday` line.

I know that I have to use the `.addClass(.complete)` method to the jQuery. So without modifying all of the `<a class="notDue" or "overDue" or "dueToday">`, how can I make sure that the right class is being modified, and not the others?

**show.html.erb**

```
 <% if item.due_date > Date.today %>
    <% if item.done? %>
      <a class="complete">
        <%= item.due_date %>
      </a>
      <a class="linkResults">
        <%= link_to "#{item.task_title}", [@todolist, item], style: "font-weight: bold;" %><br/> <br/>
      </a>
    <% else %>
      <div class="oneLine">
        <a class="notDue">
          <%= item.due_date %>
        </a>
        <a class="linkResults">
          <%= link_to "#{item.task_title}", [@todolist, item], style: "font-weight: bold;" %>
        </a>
        <a class="buttonDone" id="<%= dom_id(item) %>">
          <%= form_for([@todolist, item], remote: true, method: :put) do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :done, value: '1' %>
              <%= f.submit 'Mark Item as Done' %>
          <% end %>
        </a>
        <br/><br/>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% elsif item.due_date == Date.today %>
    <% if item.done? %>
      <a class="complete">
        <%= item.due_date %>
      </a>
      <a class="linkResults">
        <%= link_to "#{item.task_title}", [@todolist, item], style: "font-weight: bold;" %><br/> <br/>
      </a>
    <% else %>
      <div class="oneLine">
        <a class="dueToday">
          <%= item.due_date %>
        </a>
        <a class="linkResults">
          <%= link_to "#{item.task_title}", [@todolist, item], style: "font-weight: bold;" %>
        </a>
        <a class="buttonDone" id="<%= dom_id(item) %>">
          <%= form_for([@todolist, item], remote: true, method: :put) do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :done, value: '1' %>
              <%= f.submit 'Mark Item as Done' %>
          <% end %>
        </a>
        <br/><br/>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <% if item.done? %>
      <a class="complete">
        <%= item.due_date %>
      </a>
      <a class="linkResults">
        <%= link_to "#{item.task_title}", [@todolist, item], style: "font-weight: bold;" %><br/> <br/>
      </a>
    <% else %>
      <div class="oneLine">
        <a class="overdue">
          <%= item.due_date %>
        </a>
        <a class="linkResults">
          <%= link_to "#{item.task_title}", [@todolist, item], style: "font-weight: bold;" %>
        </a>
        <a class="buttonDone" id="<%= dom_id(item) %>">
          <%= form_for([@todolist, item], remote: true, method: :put) do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :done, value: '1' %>
              <%= f.submit 'Mark Item as Done' %>
          <% end %>
        </a>
        <br/><br/>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**update.js.erb**

```
$("#<%= dom_id(@todoitem) %>").hide();
alert("<%= dom_id(@todoitem) %>");
```

**applications.css**

```
.complete {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: green;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I must say I don't fully understand your question (can you try to reformulate)? And, as a sidenote, I see a lot of repetition in your template, I think you should familiarize yourself with [view partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: what is there in `@todoitem` and `item` variable also can explain what is the relation between these two

Answer (score 0):

you can use helper method and move that logic 
**if statement**
 to it

```
def dateClass date
 if item.due_date > Date.today
   return 'notDue'
 elsif item.due_date == Date.today
   return 'dueToday'
 else
   return 'overdue'
end
```

and use that helper method in your template

```
 <a class='<%= dateClass(item.due_date) %>'>
   <%= item.due_date %>
 </a>
```

this can make your template much shorter and cleaner